# NSDateFormatter Issue - Getting wrong date

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios11, nsdateformatter, foundation

In iPhone Device, getting wrong DateTime Format for customer device from our Production App.

we using DateTime format as yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss and replace empty with T
and excepted result as 2018-07-13T15:07:36, but getting date time as 2018-07-13T3:07:36TPM

Steps to Reproduce:
Method to get DateTime String

```
+ (NSString *)getCurrentLocalDateTime
{
    NSDate *localDate = [NSDate date];

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];

    NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:localDate];
    dateString = [dateString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"T"];
    NSLog(@"CURR: %@", dateString);

    return dateString; // yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss
}
```

Expected Results:
Output Data must be - 2018-07-13T15:07:36

Actual Results:
Actual Data - 2018-07-13T3:07:36TPM

issue happend in iOS Version - 11.3.1 and 11.1.2

Comment: Is there any reason you can't use a format of `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss`? (Sorry, it woks in Swift - No idea why you're getting `pm` at the end of the string)

Comment: Have you tried setting the `timezone`?

Comment: @iPeter In Device - Timezone as Brisbane.
its happens only in customer device, not happens while debug..

Comment: Set the `timeZone` of your `dateFormatter` as `NSTimeZone *tz = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];`. See if it works.

Comment: http://nsdateformatter.com/ useful for testing

Answer (score 3):

Just insert the `T` wrapped in single quotes into the date format to get the literal "T"

```
@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"
```

According to [Technical Q&A QA1480](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1480/_index.html) for fixed-format dates set the `locale` of the date formatter to the fixed value `en_US_POSIX`:

```
+(NSString *)getCurrentLocalDateTime
{
    NSDate *localDate = [NSDate date];

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setLocale:[NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"]];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"];
    NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:localDate];
    NSLog(@"CURR: %@", dateString);

    return dateString; // yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Following is the example of `NSDateFormatter`. You can use it and customise it's order of **day:month:year**

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm"];

NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
NSString *dateString = [formatter stringFromDate:currentDate];
```

Comment: return currentDate